# Can we use h2o.train_segments for h2o's autoencoder?

Tags: r, h2o, training-data, autoencoder, anomaly-detection

I have been using h2o's autoencoder (deeplearning with autoencoder=TRUE) and h2o.anomaly for anomaly detection. So far these have been performed on the entire dataset. However, now I need to build a separate model for each segment (subpopulation) of the dataset. I found h2o.train_segments so I tried it, but it gave me this error message:

Error in is.numeric(y) : argument "y" is missing, with no default

Does this mean that h2o.train_segments doesn't work for h2o's autoencoder?

Here is my code:

```
mod <- h2o.train_segments(algorithm = "deeplearning",
                          segment_columns = "some_col",
                          parallelism = 1,
                          training_frame = data.hex,
                          activation = "tanh",
                          standardize = TRUE,
                          hidden = c(10, 1, 10),
                          epochs = 5,
                          autoencoder = TRUE,
                          loss = "CrossEntropy",
                          seed = 42)
```

Thank you for your insights!

Comment: I am afraid you are right - the target of an autoencoder is the data itself. So if you have more than one variable to put in, the target is more than column also. Therefore it is something special in terms of implementation and probably this speciallty has not been solved for the segmentation algorithm (?yet?). The manual of h2o says that the training data must contain the informed X and Y (https://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/training-models.html#training-segments) which is not possible for an auto encoder, given that X has more than one column... anyhow you can concat h2o directly

Comment: Thanks DPH. That was the website I visited this morning. I was hoping it would work by specifying autoencoder=TRUE, but it still asks for the Y column. Do you know how I can contact h2o directly?

Comment: I see that you tried the googlegroup already, this leaves you with their github https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-3 also you could try their with the nearest office: https://www.h2o.ai/company/contact/

Comment: Thanks DPH! I will check their github.

Answer (score 0):

Training segments is for supervised models only. Deep learning is supported but only for supervised learning. Autoencoder is not supervised (does not need a target column, `y`), so it won't work. You will need to loop through each segment individually to do training.

Comment: Thanks Neema for your response!